# Modify multiple columns at same time in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, edit

I don't know how to say it clearly, that is maybe why i did not find the answer, but i want to edit the values of two different columns at the same time, while they are the identifying columns.

For example this is the data :

```
> data = data.frame(name1 = c("John","Jake","John","Paul"),
           name2 = c("Paul", "Paul","John","John"),
           value1 = c(0,0,1,0),
           value2 = c(1,0,1,0))
```

```
> data
  name1 name2 value1 value2
1  John  Paul      0      1
2  Jake  Paul      0      0
3  John  John      1      1
4  Paul  John      0      0
```

I would like to edit the values of the first row so the first row become Jake & John instead of John & Paul, and so i would like to combine these two lines of code for doing it at the same time :

```
data$name1[(data$name1 == "John" & data$name2 == "Paul")] <- "Jake"
data$name2[(data$name1 == "John" & data$name2 == "Paul")] <- "John"
```

Should be a simple trick but i dont have it !
Also, i should do that on larger datasets each modification can appear on multiple lines, and i cant know on which rows will be the modification

Comment: `data[1, ] <- c("B", "D")` will do.

Comment: Wont help me that much because i want to occurate this on large datasets, while i dont know on which rows are the things i will modify

Comment: From what I understand you want to modify the rows on a certain condition. Check out `dplyr::rowwise` in combination with `dplyr::c_across`.

Comment: Yes, and the columns i want to modify are both part of the condition. Thanks i will take a look at these !

Comment: Probably providing a more direct example which captures the condition(s) would let us help you better.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clearer, because i have other columns then that i dont want to modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

```
data[data$col1 == "A" & data$col2 == "B", ] <- list("B", "D")
data

#  col1 col2
#1    B    D
#2    A    C
#3    B    A
#4    B    B
```

Comment: I edited my question because it was unclear that i had other columns after the two firsts.

Comment: @BPeif You can include only the columns that you want to change. 1. By column numbers - `data[data$name1 == "John" & data$name2 == "Paul", 1:2] <- list("B", "D")`. 2. By column names - `data[data$name1 == "John" & data$name2 == "Paul", c('name1', 'name2')] <- list("B", "D")`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(
    name1=
      case_when(
        name1=="John" & name2=="Paul" ~ "Jake",
        TRUE ~ name1
      ),
    name2=
      case_when(
        name1=="John" & name2=="Paul" ~ "John",
        TRUE ~ name2))
```